# live streaming audio or video

Tags: live, audio-streaming

Im using windows media encoder 9,windows media services 2009,windows media server 2003 for live streaming audio........how can i configure for pull method in windows media services
what are all the steps should i follow for live streaming......Please give me some links to  configure the windows media services....
pls help im waiting for ur reply